# jqueryui tabs crashing IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, tabs

I've got a site running with jQuery and some Flash mixed in, all was well until I added some code to enable JQueryUI tabs.  Now it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE it crashes and forces compatability mode, which breaks the page.

http://bdindependent.com/oneworld1/solar.html

If anyone has any insight, please let me know.  Everything else seems to be working fine... but when the div with the tabs is setup, it crashes IE.  :(  Haven't seen much about this particular issue.

Comment: I considered taking a look - we deal with lots of browser-compat issues and we use JQueryUI - but you've committed the unpardonable sin of playing sound on a webpage without asking me first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the error on the Chrome Browser
`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`
I think Javascript is mistaking jQuery as a variable. If your trying to use jQuery I think you may want to use the $ sign. Hope I helped.
Edit: forgot to say the line. jquery.colorbox.js:926

Comment: The jQuery library does create a `jQuery` variable.